# I am unable to assign difference of two elements of 2 dimensional array to element of other array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Below is the code, which is breaking my head since two days.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N;
    int A[1][N-1];
    int B[1][N-1];

    std::cout << "ENTER NO OF ROUND" << '\n';
    std::cin >> N;
    for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
            int i =0;
            std::cout << "enter the scores" << '\n';
            std::cin >> A[i][j]>>A[i+1][j];

            if (A[i][j] > A[i+1][j])
            {
                    B[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[i+1][j];
                    B[i+1][j] = 1;

            }
            if (A[i][j] < A[i+1][j])
            {
                    B[i][j] = A[i+1][j] - A[i][j];
                    B[i+1][j] = 2;
            }

    }
    std::cout << A[0][0]<<A[1][0] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Here in line `18` line `19` and line`23` line`24`i should get difference of two elements of array `A[1][N-1]` Which is  then assigned to a element in array `B[1][N-1]`,but am unable get the correct result ,rather am getting a random number.
help me getting through this

Comment: `int N;` - Okay, so you declare an `N`, but what's its value for you to use it in the very next line?

Comment: `[N-1]` is an evil extension since it's not a compiler time constant.  Don't do that.  use `constexpr int N` or std::vector depending on your plan

Comment: You need to pick up a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Uninitialized and not-a-compile-time-constant `N` is not the only problem, you're accessing out of bounds when you do `A[anything_but_0]`, same with `B`...

Comment: What is the value of the `N` variable in line 6 and line 7?

Comment: Aside: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: I'd also add to UKMonkey's last comment that you don't even use that `using` directive, so what's the point of having it at all ? (btw, if you're compiling with clang or gcc, at the very least, turn on -Wall which includes -Wunitialized, that would have given you a warning on that unitialized N, on other compilers there should be similar options)

Comment: thanks @StoryTeller

Comment: Your error most likely comes from reading from and writing to uninitilized data, as @LogicStuff has pointed out. I explained it below.

Answer (score 3):

You use uninitialized data, so anything can happen.

You declare the `N` variable:

```
int N;
```

And then, in the very next line, without assigning any value, you use it to create two arrays using `N` as a size:

```
int A[1][N-1];
int B[1][N-1];
```

This already is a starting point for disaster. Moreover, declaring an array with size `[N - 1]` is not technically correct - `N` is a variable, so cannot be used to declare array in this manner. It's a compiler extension (are you using Visual Studio?). If value of `N` is known, declare it as:

```
static constexpr size_t N = value;
```

If it is read at runtime, create your arrays with `new` or, much better, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to make your code robust and less error-prone.

The second thing is, that `A` array is declared as `int A[1][N-1];`, but you do the following:

```
int i = 0;
....
if (A[i][j] > A[i+1][j])
```

Which results in reading `A[1][j]`, which does not exist - in C++ we start indexing from 0! You also modify those non-existing elements:

```
std::cin >> A[i][j] >> A[i+1][j];
```

which most likely will result in writing to memory that belongs to `B` array.

---

Small notes:

- `using namespace std` seems redundant, as you write `std::` everywhere
- what is the point of two-dimensional array `[M][N]` if `M = 1`?

Comment: i am using ATOM editor ,after declaring the `int N` i have added the `cin` for `N`,after that i have declared the two arrays `A[1][N-1]`and `B[1][N-1]`,this working for me ,thanks @Mateusz Grzejek

Comment: @Samdare Consider accepting an answer that best addresses your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::vector`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you need arrays with size determined at run-time. The C [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) you use are not supported in C++.

```
std::cout << "ENTER NO OF ROUND" << '\n';
int N = 0;
std::cin >> N;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> A(2, std::vector<int>(N));
std::vector<std::vector<int>> B(2, std::vector<int>(N));
```

And note that you need 2 x N array because you read both `A[i][j]` and `A[i+1][j]` and your `for` loop is from [0 to N-1] -- N times.

Comment: thanks @A. A its working

Comment: And you need to print your `B`s in a loop at the end, not just `A[0][0]<<A[1][0]`. And some N sanity checks would be good because everything will break with negative numbers :)